# import react(lowercase) vs import React(Uppercase)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I'm trying to import react in lowercase

`import react from 'react'`(lowercase)

Into my component
I know I've typed it in lowercase here 
and actually it does get corrected when I turn it into Uppercase

`import React from 'react'` (uppercase)

here is my code

```
import react from 'react'
class Test extends react.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                hi there
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**here is what i get as error when it's in lowercase:**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
```

**my question is why does this happen?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSX is just sugar for `React.createElement` calls](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwEwlgbgfAFmAEAXGBTATi4B6c0g&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.4.3&externalPlugins=), so if you name the React import to `react`, `React` will not be defined.

If you for some reason want to change to `react.createElement` and import `react`, [you can change the pragma with e.g. a `// @jsx react.createElement` comment](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=PTAEAECsGcA9QE4FMCGBjALgOjclGkBRAGyQFskA7DAKBoB4ATASwDcA-AC2dA06WT1gLDkA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.4.3&externalPlugins=).

Comment: Just an update: React 17 and some older specified major versions now include a new JSX transform that does not require this explicit React import. See https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to `import React from react`.

The code looking like plain HTML is actually JSX, which after webpack transpilation uses `React.createElement`

```js
import React from 'react'
class Test extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                hi there
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using render function inside the component class, it converts the above jsx syntax to React.createElement. This reference error is actually of this "React".